# Confusing on Kuratowski's ordered pair definition.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So, I came across Pugi's post and still was confused about the definition: [Kuratowski Definition of Ordered Pairs, ZFC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308064/kuratowski-definition-of-ordered-pairs-zfc)

definition (x,y) = {{x},{x,y}}

how would I expressed ordered pair (4,2)? will it be {{4},{4,2}} so the question is why isn't y = {4,2} not y = 2. For (1,1) = {{1},{1,1}} = {{1},{1}} = {{1}} so the ordered pair of (1,1) is the set {{1}}? So lost on this definition.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  You do realize the difference between a parentheses `(` and a bracket `{` and the differences in what they are used for in set theory, don't you?  "*why isn't $y=\{4.2\}$ not $y=2$*"  I do not understand this due to poor grammar and a baffling question.  For the ordered pair $(4,2)$ you have the second element of the ordered pair is $2$.  Full stop.  Period.

Comment: Now... expressing the ordered pair as a set of sets according to the kuratowski definition, you will indeed have $(4,2) = \{\{4\},\{4,2\}\}$.  On the left that is an ordered pair, the second element of which is $2$.  On the right that is a set of sets, a one element set and a two-element set, one element set only containing the first of the numbers from the original ordered pair and the two element set containing both the first and the second elements from the original ordered pair.

Comment: If your question is why we used $\{4,2\}$ as an element of the set of sets version instead of just $\{2\}$, it was so that we could distinguish between the ordered pairs $(4,2)$ and $(2,4)$ since these are meant to be distinct and unequal while on the other hand $\{\{4\},\{2\}\}$ is equal as a set to $\{\{2\},\{4\}\}$.